# Output in another Activity do not work

Tags: android, android-activity, output

I working on a speech recognition on Android Studio. How can I let the output of my spoken input be in the second activity? This is what I tried so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView voiceInput;
    private ImageView speakButton;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        voiceInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
        speakButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                askSpeechInput();
            }
        });
    }

    // Showing google speech input dialog
    private void askSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Hi speak something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        }
    }

    // Receiving speech input
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part is for the **output responsible**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                voiceInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more information please let me know and sorry for the dumb question, I think the solution is very easy but I couldn't fine them!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if I got you right, but you can do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
      case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY",result);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

and recover data in onCreate() of SecondActivity:

`onCreate(){
 ...
 ArrayList<String> result =  (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KEY);
}`